# Azure function binding to container error when unzipping file to blob storage

Tags: c#, binding, azure-functions, unzip

I have been trying to set up a Blobtrigger function that when a zip file is uploaded to a container it unzips and uploads it to the same container. I got the solution from [Azure Function: Unzip file works in debug but not in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306382/azure-function-unzip-file-works-in-debug-but-not-in-production).

```
public static class Function1
   {
       [FunctionName("Function1")]
       public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("raw-nppes/{inputBlobName}", Connection = "key")] Stream inputBlob, string inputBlobName,
           Binder binder,
           ILogger log)
       {
           log.LogInformation($"Blob trigger function received blob\n Name:{inputBlobName} \n Size: {inputBlob.Length} Bytes");

           if (Path.GetExtension(inputBlobName)?.ToLower() == ".zip")
           {
               // We use the first char of the input file name as a dynamic part in the container. (Note: You should check if this is a valid char for the container name)
               var container = $"my-dynamic-container-{inputBlobName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()}";
               var attributes = new Attribute[]
               {
                       new BlobAttribute($"{container}", FileAccess.ReadWrite),
                       new StorageAccountAttribute("AzureWebJobsStorage")
               };
               var outputContainer = await binder.BindAsync<CloudBlobContainer>(attributes);
               await outputContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

               var archive = new ZipArchive(inputBlob);
               foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
               {
                   // we write the output files to a directory with the same name as the input blob. Change as required
                   var blockBlob = outputContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{inputBlobName}/{entry.FullName}");
                   using (var fileStream = entry.Open())
                   {
                       if (entry.Length > 0)
                       {
                           log.LogInformation($"Extracting - {entry.FullName} to - {blockBlob.Name}");
                           await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
           else
           {
               log.LogInformation("Not a zip file. Ignoring");
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I got this error: **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer'**

with this possible cause: **Tried binding to 'Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory, Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0**

I don't know what that possible cause actually means. I have looked EVERYWHERE on here, github,  and social.msdn but no answer. I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your assembly is too old, please install the latest `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob` assembly:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/11.2.2

Then use `using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob;` instead of `using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;`.

The `csproj` file like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob" Version="11.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Regarding the difference between them, you can refer to this post：

[What is the difference between the Microsoft.Azure.Storage and WindowsAzure.Storage Nuget packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53214947/what-is-the-difference-between-the-microsoft-azure-storage-and-windowsazure-stor)

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention on the "Important" section of the Changelog!

I was doing the same error.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/releases/tag/storage-v4.0.0

> Important Storage namespaces have changed, so you may need to update
> your code if you are using any of the Storage types directly. Your
> code may continue to compile as you may have an implicit reference to
> the old Storage SDK, but it will fail at runtime if these have not
> been updated in your code:
>
> For blobs and queues, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.* namespaces are
> now Microsoft.Azure.Storage.*. For tables, the namespaces are now
> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.*.

Check your using ;)